# Creating profile page for devise user RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to RoR and am struggling with what seems to be this basic project requirement.

I am using Devise for user authentication which works fine and upon registering a user account with Devise I am using a custom redirect in the registrations controller to a new page where the user can create their profile. After the registration I keep getting the following error:

"First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Code below:

**Registrations Controller:**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_path(resource)
  end
end
```

**Create New profile page:**

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**Profile controller:**

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController

def new
 @profiles = current_user.build_profile
end

def create
 @profiles = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile].permit( :name))
end 

end
```

**Profile model:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

end
```

**User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

validates :name, presence: true

has_one :profile

end
```

**DB Schema file:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131124211354) do

  create_table "profiles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: Why do you have a profile table at all? I don't understand the rationale for this schema when your user table duplicates all the essential information. Anyhow, apparently profile.name is nil, and I can't tell how/where you're trying to set it, but I'm guessing it's in the user_controller.rb, which you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ProfileController, you assign `@profiles = current_user.build_profile`, but in your form, you reference `form_for @profile do |f|`. Note the difference in pluralization. Change it to @profile in the controller, and you should be good to go...

Comment: The way I got there is @profile is the first argument in form, in your case. In order for it to be nil or empty, it would have to have not been assigned, or failed a lookup, or something...